# Iterating through text files in blob storage, using Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

New to Azure here. I recently took over the overhauling of a project where data from unstructured text files is extracted and inserted to database tables, using Visual Basic.

To make a long story short, this VB-script had many issues, so I am in the process of rewriting it using Powershell. It is not very complex, just basically checks the files row by row and extracts data using different start and stop information, below is a small example :

```
$fileName = ""
$fileContents = ""
$filePath = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\share\Batch -Exclude csv

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $filePath.Count; $i++) {
    $fileName = $filePath[$i].Name
    $fileContents = Get-Content $filePath[$i].FullName
    
    getTempLog $fileContents
    getAiringLog $fileContents
    getSteamLog $fileContents
    getProductionSummary $fileContents
}

function getTempLog {
    param ($fileContents)

        $tempLogStart = 0

        $fileContents | foreach-object {
         # end condition
        if ([int]$TempLogStart -eq 1 -and $_ -like "Genomluftning Flöde (m3/h) log:*") {
            break
        }

        #output tempLog data
        if ([int]$TempLogStart -eq 1) {
            Write-Host $_.Substring(0, 14) #this should go into database
            Write-Host $_.Substring(24, 4)
        }

        # start condition
        if ($_ -like "Temperature log:*") {
            $TempLogStart = 1
        }
    }
    
}
```

Things got a bit more complicated of course, when it was decided that this solution should move into the cloud, and the files uploaded into Azure Blob Storage.

Creating an Azure function with Blob Storage as input was not a big deal, but trying to read the blobs the same way as I did when they were local files, i.e

```
$inputBlob | foreach-object {

}
```

doesn't work well since it seems as if the blob input variable is treated as one long continuous string. Am I totally going about this the wrong way?

Comment: How do you initialize $inputBlob? In your code, $fileContents contains an array of text lines because Get-Content parses the file content into separate text lines. You may need to do the same with your blob content.

Comment: Anatoli Beliaev - At the moment I have set up an Azure function which takes a blob as a string input variable. I have simply tried to use a foreach-object method on it. Get-AzStorageBlobContent was in my mind, but that command also wants to download the blob. I would like to read the blob and extract the data and send it on without downloading.

Comment: OK, a simple $inputblob.Split([Environment]::NewLine) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Diamant suggested in the comment section, to iterate through text file in blob storage using PowerShell, we can use the below command:

```
$inputblob.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
```